# Swapping Nodes into Ascending Order

Tags: java, nodes, compare-and-swap

I have a method that adds elements into a doubly linked list, and swaps elements into ascending order if the first element is greater than the second element. If I input 23, 24, 16, it skips swapping 23 and 24 because those are good, and then it swaps 23 and 16 fine. Then when it goes back into the `for` loop I get an error saying that `first.getNext()` is null. I can see that next is getting lost in the swapping, and I tried wrestling with some fixes but have not been able to get it right.

```java
@Override
public void add(T element) throws NullPointerException{
    DoubleLinearNode<T> newNode = new DoubleLinearNode<T>(element);  // Calls constructor to create a new node with data set to parameter.

    if(element == null)                                                     
        throw new NullPointerException("Cannot add a null element"); // Throws exception when parameter is null.

    if(isEmpty()) {                                                  // Add a single node.
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode; 
        count++;
        modChange++;
    }   
    else {                                                           // Add node to the back.
        tail.setNext(newNode);
        newNode.setPrevious(tail);
        tail = newNode; 
        count++;
        modChange++;
    }
    //} 
    DoubleLinearNode<T> hold = null;
    DoubleLinearNode<T> first = null;                               // First element in list.
    DoubleLinearNode<T> second = null;                              // Second element in list.

    if(size() > 1) {                                                // If there are 2 elements to compare then swap. 
        for(first = head; first.getNext() != null; first = first.getNext()) {  
            for(second = first.getNext(); second != null; second = second.getNext()) {
                if(first.getData().compareTo(second.getData()) > 0) {
                    hold = first;  
                    first = second;  
                    second = hold;
                    System.out.println(first.getData());
                    System.out.println(second.getData());
                }
            }  
        }  
    }
}
```

I tried using this code to swap nodes but then I get an error saying that `hold` is null.

```java
hold.setData(first.getData());
first.setData(second.getData());  
second.setData(hold.getData());
```

Comment: There's no need to swap.  When adding, simply find the position where the value should be and insert it into that position.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. As mentioned in the comments, you do not need to swap, just find the insertion point and relink from both sides:

```
 @Override
    public void add(T element) {
        DoubleLinearNode<T> newNode = new DoubleLinearNode<>(element);

        if (element == null)
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot add a null element");

        //Add first node
        if (isEmpty()) {                                                  
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        } else {        
            //I would suggest to extract the following logic to 
            // a dedicated methods to find the insertion point and another to do the insertion
            //The head needs to be replaced
            if (head.getData().compareTo(newNode.getData()) > 0) {
                newNode.setNext(head);
                head.setPrevious(newNode);
                head = newNode;
            } else {
                DoubleLinearNode<T> node = head.getNext();                              
                while (node != null) {
                    if (node.getData().compareTo(newNode.getData()) > 0) {
                        DoubleLinearNode<T> previous = node.getPrevious();
                        newNode.setNext(node);
                        node.setPrevious(newNode);
                        previous.setNext(newNode);
                        newNode.setPrevious(previous);
                        break;
                    }
                    node = node.getNext();
                }
                //If no insertion point found add it to the tail
                if (node == null) {
                    tail.setNext(newNode);
                    newNode.setPrevious(tail);
                    tail = newNode;
                }
            }
        }
        count++;
        modChange++;
    }
```

Few more notes, `throws NullPointerException` it's not needed at all. It is a runtime exception. It's also incorrectly used, you should throw `UnsupportedOperationException` or `IllegalArgumentException` in such cases. But is it really needed to throw an exception? It's a bad practice to control the program flow by exceptions. If I was implementing this, I would maybe just do nothing in case of `null` element or change the method `add` to return a `boolean` indicating whether the addition was successful or not and return `false` in case of `null` element.
You used `for` loops where `while` loop is a better fit, it works with for loop as well, but it's less readable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately it's not sorting a list though.

Comment: I had originally tried to insert while adding but was not able to get that right either.

Comment: do you have an example where it's not sorting?

Comment: For the list:
        list.add(23);
        list.add(24); 
        list.add(16);
        list.add(3); 
        list.add(7);
        list.add(17); 
        list.add(9); 
        list.add(13); 
        list.add(14); 
        list.add(1);          It returns 1 3 16 14 13 9 7 23 17 24

Comment: Do you think my attempt at swapping is far off? Also, what is the benefit in the recommendation to sort while adding versus sorting after a list is created?

Comment: I mixed up the insertion part, it's corrected now.

Comment: swapping does a lot of unnecessary operation. regarding sort while adding vs sorting after list is created, in your code snipped you are trying to sort after each addition, don't you? or what was the intention?

Comment: Yes I was trying to swap while adding nodes. Wasn't sure if it is better to do that, or fill the list up and then swap. I guess it would be better to do while adding nodes because this list does not have a fixed size so there is no way to know when a client will stop adding to the list.

Comment: it depends on what you want to achieve. if you want the list always sorted, then doing that while adding elements will ensure that. if you also allow unsorted list and sort only when needed then ad hoc sorting would be better